# Crystal return negative number when using .. between two positives

Tags: crystal-lang

Crystal strangely seems to output negative numbers. 
The code i'm using is

```
(1..10000000000).each do |num|
  if num % 10000000 == 0
    if num < 0
      puts "error #{num}"
      exit
    else
      puts num
    end
  end
end
```

This ouputs just before it exits `2140000000` and then `error -2140000000`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Crystal by default integers have type Int32, so when you define Range(Int32, Int64) `(1..10000000000)` it can't go from Int32 to Int64. It'll add sign bite to max Int32 number (`2147483647`) and go with negative numbers.

So if you'll run next code:

```
max_32 = 2147483647
already_64 = 2147483649

(max_32..already_64).each do |num|
 puts num
end
```

it'll never stop )))

```
puts 2147483647 + 1 # -2147483648
```

In your case you have to define types of your Range:

```
(1.to_i64..10000000000.to_i64).each do |num|
  ....... your next code
```

that will work!

Comment: Better use Int64 literals instead of calling `#to_i64`: `(1_i64..10000000000_i64)`. The method call might be optimized by LLVM, but it's nevertheless cleaner this way.

Answer (score 3):

The *integers* in the range `(1..10000000000)`, are *wrapping* round to the negative -2,147,483,648 after encountering 2,147,483,647.

This is common behaviour when working with 32 bit 2's complement signed integral types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know crystal-lang but a lot of languages have a maximum value for numbers before it circles around to -maximum value.  Maybe it is rapping around the max value.